# Blank menu bar in LXDE

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-environments, lxde

[image]

As depicted above, I have a blank menu bar in my LXDE desktop environment. I am running this desktop with regular Ubuntu 13.04.

I have tried re-installing LXDE:

```sh
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop
```

This has not fixed it however. Does any one have ideas on what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the bar and press Add/remove panel items. Then press panel applets. Then Add. then a list will pop up. press Menu. You should also add Task Bar (Window List).